# How can I use an existing text block as a data source?

Tags: python

I don't want to load data from an external file location. Instead I want the user to drop an xml file into an open text window, then run a script that can use this file as a data source. The file will always have the extension .csv. But I don't know how to search for an existing datablock like this?

Currently its a hard coded path for testing:

```
# READ INPUT FILE

fp   = "/Users/davidmcsween/Downloads/TEST LIST.csv"

file = csv.reader( open( fp, newline='' ), delimiter=',' )

nameIdx = 3 # Column index of text object's name
bodyIdx = 4 # Column index of text object's body (content)
```

I had hoped that I could use

```
fp   = bpy.data.texts[", *,".csv"].name = "", *,".csv"
```

But this fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In as much as you can get all the texts in a blend file with `[text for text in bpy.data.texts]` and the filepath is `text.filepath`.  If a file is pasted into the text editor then it will have `filepath = ""`.  I recommend using the text editor current text as your csv data.  A simple panel is added to the text editor properties, which ensures that the current csv file is

```
current_csv_file = context.edit_text
```

Firstly, a simple operator that prints out the csv data, split by "," line for line.

```
import bpy

def main(context):
    text = context.edit_text
    for line in text.lines:
        split = line.body.split(",")
        print(split)

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "text.import_csv"
    bl_label = "Import CSV"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Can make a panel in the text editor UI like so

[image]

```
import bpy

class TextPTImportCSV(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Import CSV"
    bl_idname = "TEXT_PT_import_csv"
    bl_space_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        text = context.edit_text
        return text.name[-4:].lower() == ".csv"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(context.edit_text.name)        
        layout.operator("text.import_csv")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TextPTImportCSV)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TextPTImportCSV)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

which running on the simple test file prints

```
['1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1', ' 1']
['2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2']
['3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3']
```

to the console.

EDIT: as a side note, `split` above will be a list of strings, and will need to be converted if they are other. Here is a basic way to make a key for your csv file.  Consider a file that has 4 columns, the first is an integer for frame, the next three a location.  Quite likely there is a way to use the `text.lines` as input to `csv.reader` (simple workaround would be to save to tmp file)

```
# key of csv file, [property name,  column(s), type]
key = [["frame", 0, int], # frame in col 1
       ["location", [1, 2, 3], float] # loc x, y, z in cols 1, 2, 3.
       ]
'''
data in csv like
1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
'''    
split = ['1', ' 1.0', ' 1.0', '1.0']

for prop, cols, prop_type in key:
    if isinstance(cols, list):
        val = [prop_type(split[col]) for col in cols]
    elif isinstance(cols, int):
        val = prop_type(split[cols])

    print(prop, " = ", val)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this one, can you tell me what happening in this line-  return text.name[-4:].lower() == ".csv"  I gather that it is the identifier above the button but I don't understand how the line works?

Comment: only poll (display) the panel if the last 4 letters of name, converted to lower case, are ".csv".  Arguably could have used this for the operator too.

Comment: So the usable variable for me will be "split"? That will be the csv file contents to use later?

Comment: `split` is just one line of text editor, split into a list using the "," as a delimiter.   Generally would deal with csv data on a line by line basis. Made an edit on one way to use comma split list.  Could be a way to use the text editor content (eg `text.lines` is iterable)  as input to csv reader, might put together a q on this.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by batFINGER text blocks have a name and a filepath, but if you just paste data into a text block, you might not have a filepath.

If you don't need the overhead of a custom operator, the following example is a bit more compact:

```
import bpy
import csv

def csvs():
    return [t for t in bpy.data.texts if t.name[-4:].lower() == ".csv"]

first = csvs()[0]

lines = first.as_string().splitlines() 
#lines = first.lines # those aren't actually strings

f = csv.reader(lines)
for parts in f:
    print(parts)
```

Comment: Thanks, was trying  `csv.reader(first.lines)`.  Never bothered to use `csv` before.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I really am quite ignorant so I don't understand without lots of commenting. But I will try to work through these answers. Sorry for being dumb about it.